# Multiple timers help! FLASH as3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, timer

I'm making a quiz game, there's 5 questions involved. I made a timer for the 1st question so when the user hasnt answered the question within 10secs they'll go to question 2 (another frame). 
Question 1 timer works fine, how do i get question 2 to do the exactly the same as question 1? I tried adding the same code into question 2 however it gives me an error.
Thanks

My code:

```
stop();

var count:Number = 10;
var myTimer:Timer=new Timer(1000,2);
myTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, countdown);
myTimer.start();

function countdown(event:TimerEvent):void {
count00.text=String((count)-myTimer.currentCount); 

if(count00.text == "0"){
gotoAndStop(85);
}
}


myTimer.stop();
myTimer.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, countdown);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you shouldnt be doing this over multible frames. But thats a different discussion.

You should stop your timer, remove the listener and move to next a frame in an onComplete event.

```
stop();

var count:Number = 10;
var myTimer:Timer=new Timer(1000,count);// this should be the total count
myTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, countdown);
myTimer.addEventListener(TimeEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, timerDone);
myTimer.start();

function countdown(event:TimerEvent):void {
    count00.text=String((count)-event.currentTarget.currentCount);//get currentCount from event 
}

function timerDone(e:TimerEvent):void{
    trace("Timer finishing!");
    myTimer.stop();
    myTimer.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, countdown);
    gotoAndStop(85);
}
```

Btw. you are setting the repeatCount of the timer to 2, `new Timer(1000,2);` this will give you 2 seconds countdown, not much time for a question ;) it should be `count`

Also there musst be a dynamic textField with the instance name `count00` in the same frame (not layer) as the code!!

Please always include relevant error messages in the question!

Comment: TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
 at product_fla::MainTimeline/countdown()
 at flash.utils::Timer/_timerDispatch()
 at flash.utils::Timer/tick()

Comment: then `count00` doesnt exist at this time/frame.